# Virtualenv is not allowing me to use ImageHorizonLibrary and SwingLibrary in robotframework at the same time

Tags: swing, virtualenv, robotframework

My bash_profile is set to the following:

```
export PATH=/Users/nimam/jython2.7.0/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin::/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I need to include jython as I am running the swinglibrary for the robotframework, but I would like to include ImageHorizonLibrary as well. However, i am currently not able to run the ImageHorizonLibrary. I get the following error.

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/Users/nimam/swinglibrary-demo/read_attributes.robot': Importing test library 'ImageHorizonLibrary' failed: ImportError: No module named ImageHorizonLibrary
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  /Users/nimam/jython2.7.0/bin
  /Users/nimam/jython2.7.0/Lib
  __classpath__
  __pyclasspath__/
  /Users/nimam/jython2.7.0/Lib/site-packages
CLASSPATH:
  /Users/nimam/jython2.7.0/jython.jar
  Rotarran-2.0.8-standalone.jar
```

If I comment out the export PATH in the bash_profile, it recognizes the ImageHorizonLibrary but not the SwingLibrary. I get the following error:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/Users/nimam/swinglibrary-demo/read_attributes.robot': Importing test library 'SwingLibrary' failed: ImportError: No module named SwingLibrary
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  /usr/local/bin
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
  /Users/nimam/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
```

I have a feeling I can solve this by playing around with the virtualenv. Please let me know if there is a way I can run both libraries at the same time.

Comment: Install the ImageHorizonLibrary in the jython environment. As you can see in its output, its pythonpath is just it, `/Users/nimam/jython2.7.0/Lib/site-packages`.

Comment: @Todor, I tried installing the ImageHorizonLibrary in the jython environment, but I am getting the following error: 'Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: __pyclasspath__/pip/_vendor/certifi/cacert.pem'

Comment: Put that as a separate question - with the python and jython tags, without the robotoframwork (it'll have nothing to do with RF).

Comment: Made a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51162949/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-could-not-find-a-suitable)