# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle

Tags: python, pip, jython

I am trying to install a robotframework library called ImageHorizonLibrary. However, I am running into an issue. I am trying to install it using pip in the jython environment:

```
/Users/nimam/jython2.7.0/Lib/site-packages
```

I do the following:

```
 sudo -H pip install robotframework-imagehorizonlibrary
```

And I get the following error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: __pyclasspath__/pip/_vendor/certifi/cacert.pem
```

If I try to install the library without sudo, i get the following error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/basecommand$py.class", line 228, in main
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/commands/install$py.class", line 291, in run
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/commands/install$py.class", line 291, in run
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/resolve$py.class", line 102, in resolve
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/resolve$py.class", line 102, in resolve
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/resolve$py.class", line 257, in _resolve_one
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/resolve$py.class", line 208, in _get_abstract_dist_for
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/operations/prepare$py.class", line 245, in prepare_linked_requirement
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/req/req_install$py.class", line 307, in populate_link
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/index$py.class", line 484, in find_requirement
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/index$py.class", line 442, in find_all_candidates
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/index$py.class", line 587, in _get_pages
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/index$py.class", line 705, in _get_page
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/index$py.class", line 810, in get_page
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/index$py.class", line 810, in get_page
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions$py.class", line 521, in get
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_internal/download$py.class", line 397, in request
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions$py.class", line 508, in request
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions$py.class", line 618, in send
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter$py.class", line 42, in send
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter$py.class", line 42, in send
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller$py.class", line 137, in cached_request
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize$py.class", line 98, in loads
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize$py.class", line 98, in loads
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize$py.class", line 190, in _loads_v4
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize$py.class", line 190, in _loads_v4
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback$py.class", line 119, in unpackb
  File "__pyclasspath__/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback$py.class", line 298, in feed
TypeError: can't concat memoryview to bytearray
```

Comment: did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @bunbun no I did not.

Comment: Just my €0.02: incorrectly set environmental variable ``REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE`` did it for me. Unsetting it helped.